# How to find ASGs hooked up with an ELB

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-elb

How to find ASGs hooked up with an ELB.

My problem is, I want to deregister ASG associated with and ELB. How to do that.

PS: I do not know ASG name. A way I can think of is : Find instances associated with ELB and then pass it on to find respective ASGs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use JMESpath syntax to `--query` the response of `describe-auto-scaling-groups`. The solutions below specifically select AutoScalingGroups where the array contains the given string passed as the second parameter of the JMESpath contains functions.

Both of these solutions support partial matching, and will return all load balancers matching the given pattern.

If you only need text response, use `--output text`.

### Elastic Load Balancers

Filter response set on the LoadBalancerNames array:

```
aws autoscaling describe-auto-scaling-groups --query "AutoScalingGroups[? LoadBalancerNames [? contains( @,'<YOUR LOAD BALANCER NAME HERE>')]].AutoScalingGroupName"
```

### Application Load Balancers

Filter response set on the TargetGroupARNs array:

```
aws autoscaling describe-auto-scaling-groups --query "AutoScalingGroups[? TargetGroupARNs [? contains(@, '<YOUR TARGET GROUP ARN HERE>')]].AutoScalingGroupName"
```

### Further Reading

- [AWS Documentation - aws cli describe-auto-scaling-groups](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/autoscaling/describe-auto-scaling-groups.html)
- [AWS Documentation - Controlling Command Output from the AWS Command Line Interface](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/controlling-output.html)
- [JMESPath Documentation - Contains()](http://jmespath.org/specification.html#contains)

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you know the ELB's name, you can use the [`aws autoscaling describe-auto-scaling-groups`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/autoscaling/describe-auto-scaling-groups.html) command. In the response, you'll find the attached load balancers in the `LoadBalancerNames` field. You can then use your ELB's name to find the ASG you're looking for.

Comment: I do not know ASG name and in above command I need to put ASG name in order to get data.

Comment: You only need to know the ELB name, not the ASG name. And the `aws autoscaling describe-auto-scaling-groups` command does not require you to know any ASG name in advance.